# a confuse about POST or GET variables in PHP c extensions?

Tags: php, php-extension

I an now working on a php extension writing in C . In the extension, i need get the GET or POST variables and do some work. But problems occurred, if i declare a variable in PHP script like this :

```
$_GET['q'] = 'some text on there';
```

then i try to get this variable in PHP extension like this :

```
HashTable *h;
char * ret_path;
zval * g_arr;
zval ** findarr;
g_arr = PG(http_globals)[TRACK_VARS_GET];
h = Z_ARRVAL_P(g_arr);
if(SUCCESS == zend_hash_find(h, "q", sizeof("q"), (void **)&findarr)) {
    //some code there
}else{

}
```

it can not find the variable . How does PHP deal internally with the GET or POST super-global variables in script?

Comment: Try using `EG(symbol_table)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

your maybe use the follow code:

```
zval    **carrier, **ret;
carrier = &PG(http_globals)[TRACK_VARS_GET];

if (!carrier || !(*carrier)) {
    zval *empty;
    MAKE_STD_ZVAL(empty);
    ZVAL_NULL(empty);
    return empty;
}

if (!len) {
    Z_ADDREF_P(*carrier);
    return *carrier;
}

if (zend_hash_find(Z_ARRVAL_PP(carrier), "q", 1 + 1, (void **)&ret) == FAILURE) {
    zval *empty;
    MAKE_STD_ZVAL(empty);
    ZVAL_NULL(empty);
    return empty;
}

return *ret;
```